"Forbidden" Error when adding VictoriaMetrics datasource for Grafana
I'm facing this error when trying to "save & test" VictoriaMetrics datasource. The problem is not with victoriametrics cluster because when i set up grafana on the same node where victoriametrics cluster is deployed it works fine.
When I click "save & test" in Grafana the log below appears in the grafana logs:
 Aug 27 09:33:12 <host_name> grafana-server[125410]: logger=context userId=18 orgId=1 uname=<uname>@ t=2024-08-27T09:33:12.958393356+03:00 level=info msg="Request Completed" method=POST path=/api/datasources/proxy/35/api/v1/query status=403 remote_addr=<ip_address> time_ms=4 duration=4.167245ms size=121 referer=https://<dns-name>/datasources/edit/DYsyRc3Sz handler=/api/datasources/proxy/:id/* Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

"status=403" looks like authorization error. Seems like Grafana can't reach VictoriaMetrics for some reason: network issue, bad proxy config, etc.

when i set up grafana on the same node where victoriametrics cluster is deployed it works fine

This only proves that problem is in connectivity between VictoriaMetrics and your Grafana server.
